# How do I use a htaccess redirect to force www and use the .org domain while maintaining the URL path?

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I have found this rule that does about 90% of what I want, but not quite everything. My main goals for the redirect are to 1) force www. 2) redirect .com to .org. This does that, but if I were at www.domain.com/page, it just redirects to the home page and not www.domain.org/page. How can I get it to do this last step as well?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Are the `.com` and `.org` domains pointing to the same place ie. you have 1 hosting account? Or are they 2 entirely separate hosting accounts?

Comment: The original rewrite rule wouldn't "almost work" if they weren't hosted in the same place.

Comment: They are in the same place pointed to the same folders. I just have them set up using vhosts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use your .htaccess file in the root of each site. You will be creating 2 .htaccess files, one per-site. I am assuming that you have each site defined within Apache as two separate sites. This is important to do.

In your .com site:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

In your .org site:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will do two things:

- Do a blanket redirect from your .com site to your .org site.
- Redirect any non-www request to www preserving the original request.

Comment: You are missing the `$1` on the first `RewriteRule`. However, the OPs current code would seem to suggest that both domains are actually hosted at the same place - although it's not clear, I've asked the OP to confirm.

Comment: @w3d Yes you are right! Fixed. Thanks!! I was making an assumption about how the sites were hosted. Either way, this solution should work okay. I tend to do really odd regex(s), but mostly stay out of general .htaccess stuff and why I tend to shy away from these questions. You, however, are the local regex/.htaccess guru along with bybe.

Comment: I moved the rules to my apache conf files instead and it worked beautifully. Thanks @closetnoc! One final question would be, with your exact rule, I was getting double slashes after the redirect (www.domain.org//some/page). I just took the / out in the rule and it seems to work. I'm not doing something wrong by removing that slash am I?

Comment: @Krista Removing the `/` in the _substitution_ is OK. Alternatively you could include a `/` in the _pattern_ eg. `^/(.*)$`. (Or, include the directives in a `<Directory>` section.) The reason for the difference in behaviour between server config (outside of `<Directory>` sections) and per-directory .htaccess files is that in your server config the per-directory prefix (ie. `/` - a slash in this instance) is **not** removed before pattern matching.

Comment: @w3d Thanks for chiming in while I was out. I made the edit for future users. Thanks(!) again.

Comment: @Krista I am glad it is working for you. Sorry- I was out for a while.

Answer (score 3):

That should be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The "$1" tells mod_rewrite to add the matched text from inside the parentheses in the pattern to the rewritten URL, which is what you want.

Comment: ok first I just added the $1 and tried that. It still went back to the homepage. Then, I noticed you changed ^(.*)$ to ^/(.*)$ and that broke all of them

Comment: With this being .htaccess you should omit the slash (per-directory) prefix on the `RewriteRule` pattern (or at least make it optional).

Comment: @Krista: Clear your browser cache. 301 redirects are cached by the browser, so you are probably seeing the result of the old/incorrect cached redirect.

Comment: You added a `/` to the beginning of the rewrite rule.  Rewrite rules can't begin with a slash in .htaccess, only in the apache conf file.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for pointing that out -- I've fixed it. I'm a lot more used to editing Apache conf files than .htaccess files.