# Do I have to redirect every page or just the domain?

Tags: redirects, webserver, http

Say I have a www.example.net and www.example.net and example.com is an Amazon S3 site setup to redirect all pages work fine i.e www.example.com/page1.html redirects to www.example.net/page1.html buy for another webserver I have the administrator dong the redirect and although the plain unadorned page works fine when I add a full URL including a page it doesnt work, why would that be.

In both cases, I am using a HTTP permananent rediect (301).

Comment: Can you include the redirect code?? I am sure there is something wrong. I blanket redirect that would redirect an entire site regardless of the URI.

Comment: @closetnoc Im not doing the redirect myself, asking the administrator but  compare http://songkong.net with http://songkong.net/buy.jsp

Comment: I assume that both links should go to the same place (domain/directory and then domain/directory/file)? If that is the case, the redirect has been done incorrectly. The first example in this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77987/how-do-i-use-a-htaccess-redirect-to-force-www-and-use-the-org-domain-while-main/77989#77989 is a blanket redirect to another domain. You will of course need to modify the example, but that is easily done and not technically difficult.

Comment: How are you redirecting the pages? .htaccess file or apache/nginx configuration file or any other method?

Comment: In the end I moved over to using Route53 & Amazon S3 to do all the redirection to the site.